# Print the names of test packages as they are compiled

Tags: go

Running `go build` or `go install` with `-v` will "print the names of packages as they are compiled". How do I get the same when I run `go test`? `-v` there means to output test information. When running tests on some packages, they can unexpectedly take a long time, due to long compiles for some dependencies. I'd like some visibility in to that process.

The best option I can think of is to try something like `go build -v ./...`, but I don't know if that will include building the dependencies of tests, and it's a separate step.

Comment: The "-v" flag is explicitly shadowed in `test` (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d137b745398e8313c0f086d4d044751295be6163/src/cmd/go/internal/work/build.go#L266). You can still use "-x" flag to get some verbose output or you can open a feature request to unshadow it.

Comment: "How do I get the same when I run go test?" Not at all. Except with -x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `go build` is not viable:

> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.

The `test` command doesn't have the flag to print package names. `-v` has a different meaning than `build`.

A roundabout solution is to use the debug flag `-x` and pipe the output to `grep`. The output of `-x` is unwieldy, because it's debug and it's not meant to be used in actual command pipelines.

```
go test -x ./... 2>&1 | grep -E "^cd"
```

The lines that start with `cd` are those containing the packages that are being compiled, as it `cd`'s into them.

This includes the dependencies of those tests and back and forth between test packages and the working dir `.`. Not a perfect solution, but it's something.